# Update gcc4.5 from gcc4.4

Tags: gcc

Can I update gcc-4.4 to gcc-4.5 without updating Ubuntu 11.04 to Ubuntu 11.10?
If yes then how?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 has GCC 4.5 installed by default. Check `gcc --version`. Ubuntu 11.10 has GCC 4.6 installed by default. Did you mean that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc 4.5 is the default version of gcc on Ubuntu 11.04. So just install the default package, `gcc` or `g++`, and it will also install gcc 4.5 or g++ 4.5 respectively. If you prefer you can just install `gcc-4.5` directly. So either

```
apt-get install gcc
```

or

```
apt-get install gcc-4.5
```

should work, if you really just want `gcc` (as opposed to `g++` for example).

Comment: I think installing the `gcc-4.5` package just installs the `gcc-4.5` program, but doesn't affect the plain `gcc` program? So I'd suggest option one.

Comment: Thanks ams & Faheem. Using gcc --version I got that I had already gcc 4.5 & now I also upgrade it with gcc-4.6.2.